# Unable to access enum in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, ognl

I am trying to access a java enum in thymeleaf in a case statement, but I am getting a ClassNotFoundException when trying to access it. I am not using Spring, so I am using OGNL syntax. I've confirmed that there's no typo in package or enum name, so I'm stumped as to why OGNL/Thymeleaf can't find the enum to use

Code snippet:

```
<th:block th:switch="${question.getType()}">
    <th:block th:case="${@services.question.types.QuestionType@CHECKBOX}">
        // stuff in the case statement
    </th:block>
    // More case statements for other enum values.
</th:block>
```

My error looks like this

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "@services.question.types.QuestionType@CHECKBOX" (template: "applicant/ApplicantQuestionFragment" - line 4, col 19)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:199)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:104)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.EqualsExpression.executeEquals(EqualsExpression.java:75)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.ComplexExpression.executeComplex(ComplexExpression.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:112)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:125)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardCaseTagProcessor.isVisible(StandardCaseTagProcessor.java:106)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.java:61)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587)
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: Could not get static field CHECKBOX from class services.question.types.QuestionType
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.question.types.QuestionType
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator$ThymeleafDefaultClassResolver.toClassForName(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:413)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator$ThymeleafDefaultClassResolver.classForName(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:404)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator$ThymeleafACLClassResolver.classForName(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:379)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.classForName(OgnlRuntime.java:1584)
    at ognl.ASTStaticField.isNodeConstant(ASTStaticField.java:78)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.isConstant(SimpleNode.java:343)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:202)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:586)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:550)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.executeExpression(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:340)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:178)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:104)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
```

Tried both OGNL and Spring syntax

Comment: I'm able to access basic java classes (ie @java.lang.Math@random() worked fine), but can't access any java classes in my project as far as I can tell

Comment: Show us your enum code; clarify what is at line 4 of the template (as per the error message); clarify what version of Thymeleaf you are using; take a look at [mre]. As it stands, I am not able to recreate your error using the code in your question - it works OK for me. You can [edit] your question. Someone may have an answer, but taking these steps will increase your chances of getting a solution.